# Highcharts organization change size image and position

Tags: highcharts, organization

I'm trying to make an org chart with Highcharts here I'm having trouble changing the size of the image in the boxes and squares here my code : https://jsfiddle.net/heriira_/acsfpurh/6/ and this is the design i want to make : [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTlaI.png)

```
series: [
        {
            type: "organization",
            name: "",
            keys: ["from", "to"],
            data: [
                ["A", "B"],
                ["A", "C"],
                ["A", "D"],
                ["A", "E"],
                ["A", "F"],
                ["A", "G"],
            ],
            nodes: [
                {
                    id: "A",
                    title: "CEO",
                    name: "john doe",
                    image:
                        "https://wp-assets.highcharts.com/www-highcharts-com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/17131126/Highsoft_03862_.jpg",
                },
                {
                    id: "B",
                },
                {
                    id: "C",
                },
                {
                    id: "D",
                    column: 2,
                    color: "333333",
                },
                {
                    id: "E",
                    column: 2,
                },
                {
                    id: "F",
                    column: 2,
                },
                {
                    id: "G",
                    column: 2,
                },
            ],
            colorByPoint: true,
            color: "#007ad0",
            useHTML: true,
            style: {
                padding: 1000
            },
            dataLabels: {
                color: "white",
            },
            borderColor: "white",
            nodeWidth: 65,
        },
    ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution but it's a tricky one:

1. change the dataLabel flex-direction to 'column' - it might be done by CSS or inside the `nodeFormatter` callback,
2. set the node height - here I found a bug - the first node cuts if his height is set to some fixed value,
3. As a solution to above bug I recommend to add the dummy point and hide it,

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hj1smnLq/